# PHP does not load environment variables if executed with sudo in CLI in Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, environment-variables, osx-yosemite

I am setting my environment variable as follows:

```
launchctl setenv variablename value

//For sudo

sudo launchctl setenv variablename value
```

When I check to see if the variables are set, for sudo and normal user, they are:

```
   launchctl getenv variablename
```

However, for sudo, they are not loaded in `php -i`.

If I run in terminal

```
php -i
```

I can see the variables at the end of the ouptut. But if I do:

```
sudo php -i
```

The variables do not appear. How can I make the variables appear when using `sudo` and `php` ?

Comment: Why the hell would you want to run any sort of PHP application as a sudo? That is a massive security risk right there

Comment: Maybe with this http://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables